# passing array to function

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, parameter-passing

i am trying to pass an array between two functions. The _data function is my array. It takes 3 parameters; the array itself, the size of the array and the file name of the array. So this function should get each element from the input file(.txt) and put it into the array, which it seems to do ok.

```
void _data(string dataArray[], int sizeOfArray, ifstream &fin)
{
    const int CharBuffer=20;
    char linedata[CharBuffer];
    ifstream& getline (char* s, streamsize n );

    for(int x = 0; x < sizeOfArray; x++)
    {
        fin.getline(linedata, CharBuffer);
        dataArray[x]=linedata;
        cout << dataArray[x] << endl;
    }
}

ifstream& operator>>(ifstream &fin, ArrayIntStorage &AIS)
{
    string acwData[10000];
    _data(acwData, 10000, fin);
    return fin;
}
```

but in the next part I need to output the values from my array to a text file which I must do in a separate function.

**So my question is, how can I access the data stored in the acwData array above in the function below?**(or any other function)

```
ofstream& operator<<(ofstream& fout, ArrayIntStorage& AIS)
{
    return fout;
}
```

do i need to initialize my array function differently to include a return type?

Comment: What is the `ArrayIntStorage& AIS` parameter?  Is it relevant to your question?

Comment: @quamrana no it's not, that is for a different function which I still need to implement

Comment: @Marc: I asked because I suspected that the `_data` function should write its input data into `AIS` and that would be the way of transferring it to `'any other function'`.

Comment: @quamrana ok that sounds right. So how would I get the `_data` function to write the data into a parameter such as `AIS`?

Comment: @Marc:  Make `AIS` a parameter of `_data` and write, say, an `add` member for `ArrayIntStorage` which takes `linedata`.

Comment: WHAT are you actually trying to do? You have asked numerous question on similar issues (and I've answered one) and all show you have quite a few gaps in your knowledge. Is this homework? Are you trying to learn all this on your own? In both cases there should be some preliminary courses you need to master before doing this exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things wrong with this code:

```
 void _data(string dataArray[], int sizeOfArray, ifstream &fin)
```

Names that begin with an underscore are reserved for the C++ implementation in most circumstances - don't use them in your own code unless you have read the C++ Standard fairly closely, which I suspect you have not.

```
 ifstream& getline (char* s, streamsize n );
```

Don't declare standard library functions yourself. This function is declared in `<iostream>` so you should #include that header.

The use of an array is suspect. As you are obviously using C++ and the standard library, why not use a `vector<string>` which you should pass into your function as  a reference.